# What VB or VBA interpreters or compilers are available for the Windows operating system?

Tags: vba, vb6

I am looking for an interpreter (compiler would work too) for Visual Basic or VBA. I am not looking for any kind of UI support. Basically, I have a series of somewhat complex VBA modules which make no reference to any external DLLs and make no use of any user interfaces. Is there any such tool available short of having Microsoft Office or Microsoft Visual Basic for the Windows operating system?

Comment: are these vba modules that were running within an office product or vbscript files with .vbs extension?

Comment: They run with an office product but they don't need to, exactly. They are functions which returned modified results of input (or a cell). For testing purposes no cell data is required.

Comment: The author of `oletools` is working on a standalone VBA engine for this kind of thing, but it's not released yet:

https://twitter.com/decalage2/status/571778745222242305

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VBA only exists as an embedded "macro language" inside a host application like Excel.  At one time you could even buy the SDK to embed VBA in your own applications, but there was never any "stand alone VBA."

VBScript is close to VBA and VB in syntax and semantics, but it also requires a host.  Common desktop hosts include WSH, MSHTA, and the Vista/Win7 "gadget" framework.  That's probably your best bet if it meets your needs.

It is remotely possible to do what you want using VB5CCE (Control Creation Edition) if you can find it.  This was free, but could not compile to EXEs.  It might have worked as an interpreter however by running it with the `/run` switch.  I'm not certain of that though.

There are 3rd party freebies as well such as [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org/) which uses a very VB/VBA-like syntax.

Update: VB5CCE *does not* support the `/run` switch.

Comment: So far, it looks like Jabaco is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a peek if VB.NET is a fit.  Visual Studio Express ... I'm not sure what the free version leaves out though.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-basic-express

Comment: It leaves out a ton of things, yet still not nearly enough to matter to a shadetree coder.  Aside from the radical syntactic, semantic, conceptual, and IDE changes which might take some getting used to it can be a good option.  Especially if no level of VBA compatibility is required.

Comment: VB.NET <> VB/VBA, that's undeniable